# nuxt3のプラグイン関数をstorybookで使えるように設定する方法を知りたい。

Tags: typescript, vue.js

nuxt3のプロジェクトでstorybookを使用してコンポーネント開発を進めたいのですが、`./plugins/`以下に作成した下記に記載のプラグイン関数(`$getLang()`)を使用しているストーリーをレンダリングする際に`TypeError: _ctx.$getLang is not a function.`とエラーが出ます。どのように`.storybook/preview.ts`に関数を設定すれば良いのでしょうか。

- plugins/i18n.ts

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue3-i18n'
import en from '@/locales/en.json'
import ja from '@/locales/ja.json'
import zh_TW from '@/locales/zh_TW.json'
import zh_CN from '@/locales/zh_CN.json'

interface I18nOptions {
  locale: string
  messages: Record<string, object>
}

const getBrowserLanguage = (): string => {
  if (process.client) {
    return window.navigator.language
  }
  return 'en'
}

const getLocaleFromCookie = (): string | null => {
  // Read from cookie
  const cookie = useCookie<string>('locale')
  if (cookie.value) {
    return cookie.value
  }
  return null
}

const LANGS = {
  EN: 'en',
  JP: 'ja',
  TW: 'zh-TW',
  CN: 'zh-CN',
}

const getLocale = (): string => {
  const browserLanguage = getBrowserLanguage()
  if (Object.values(LANGS).includes(browserLanguage)) {
    return browserLanguage
  }
  const cookieLocale = getLocaleFromCookie()
  if (cookieLocale && Object.values(LANGS).includes(cookieLocale)) {
    return cookieLocale
  }
  return 'en'
}

const messages: Record<string, object> = { en, ja, 'zh-tw': zh_TW, 'zh-cn': zh_CN }

const i18nOptions: I18nOptions = {
  locale: getLocale().toLowerCase(),
  messages,
}

const i18n = createI18n(i18nOptions)

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxt) => {
  nuxt.vueApp.use(i18n)

  return {
    provide: {
      t: () => null,
      getLang: (key: string, params?: Array<string>) => {
        if (!key) return ''
        return i18n.t(key, params)
      },
      setLocale: (value: string) => {
        i18n.setLocale(value)
      },
      getLocale: () => i18n.getLocale(),
    },
  }
})
```

- package.json(一部抜粋)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.8.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.27",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.27",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.27",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.27",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^7.0.27",
    "@storybook/vue3-vite": "^7.0.27",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.12",
    "nuxt": "^3.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "storybook": "^7.0.27",
    "storybook-addon-nuxt": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vue3-i18n": "^1.1.5"
  },
```

- .storybook/main.ts

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/vue3-vite'

export const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-interactions'],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/vue3-vite',
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag',
  },
}
```

- .storybook/preview.ts

```
import type { Preview } from '@storybook/vue3'

export const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
}
```